# Insert SYSTIMESTAMP for Timestamp field

Tags: oracle, systimestamp

I have three timestamps in my SQL Table.

```
Column Name     Data Type   Nullable Data_Default

STATUS_TIMSTM   TIMESTAMP(6)    No  (null)
CREATED_TIMSTM  TIMESTAMP(6)    No  SYSTIMESTAMP  
UPDATED_TIMSTM  TIMESTAMP(6)    No  (null)
```

```sql
INSERT INTO "TABLE_NAME" ("STATUS_TIMSTM","CREATED_TIMSTM","UPDATED_TIMSTM")
VALUES(TIMESTAMP '2020-12-10 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-06-15 00:00:00',TIMESTAMP '2020-06-15 00:00:00');
```

The above works correctly.

How do I insert the current `systimestamp`?

I've tried several options: curdate(), now(), systimestamp().

> I usually get errors such as Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "NOW": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Oracle != mysql.  Please correct the tag.

Comment: if you insert string `'2020-12-10 00:00:00'`, all you need it to use `To_date('2020-12-10 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')` <-- check exact syntax with oracle

Comment: Apologies - I'm not looking to insert the dates above - simply placeholders. I want the current system time to be inputted as part of the record for the timestamps. I want to replace the hardcoded dates with (now(), systimestamp() - IDK, these don't seem to work.)

Comment: @T.S. `localdate` is not an Oracle function, and you missed `current_timestamp`

Comment: `sysdate`, `systimestamp`, `localtimestamp`, `current_timestamp` ____ @WernfriedDomscheit --> Danke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a DATA DEFAULT, only inserting data in below format must populate the `CREATED_TIMSTM` column with current `TIMESTAMP`.

```
INSERT INTO "TABLE_NAME" ("STATUS_TIMSTM","UPDATED_TIMSTM")
VALUES(TIMESTAMP '2020-12-10 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-06-15 00:00:00');
```

Here is a simplified [DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=52161b00de0ceb550b87d2e51ee04162) demonstrating the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `current_timestamp`:

```
create table t (x   TIMESTAMP(6));

insert into t (x) values (current_timestamp);
```

Of course, `systimestamp` should also work.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=930eca2904422a292fd03ac90cbd6f33) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: If the OP asked about `systimestamp`, why would you show him how to use `current_timestamp` and only mention `systimestamp` at the end as an afterthought? At the very least, you might explain to him that the two do **different** things. One returns the session timestamp, the other the (database server) OS timestamp. They may reflect different time zones.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you would

```
insert into my_table(timestamp_column) values (systimestamp);
```

Notice that the function call does **not** include parentheses after the function name. Oracle is pretty odd in this regard; functions that don't take parameters, but that you define *yourself*, **must** use empty parentheses, but similar functions (no parameters) that are provided by  Oracle **must** be used without parentheses. Only Oracle knows why it's inconsistent this way. This explains why your attempt was failing.

(Actually, some experimentation with `systimestamp` shows that it **can** take an argument - a positive integer which shows how many decimal places you want for seconds! In any case, you can't use it with empty parentheses.)

There are other "current" timestamp functions, but they do different things. `systimestamp` returns the timestamp of the computer system that hosts the database server. (Note that this may, and often is, *different from* the database timestamp.) In any case, `systimestamp` is by far the most commonly used of these; similar to `sysdate` for dates.

Beware of time zone though. `systimestamp` returns timestamp **with time zone**. By inserting it into a `timestamp` column, you are losing information. Is that OK for your business application?